# eslint `forbid-prop-types` rule cause a warning in firefox console window

Tags: reactjs, eslint

As the document says [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md)

> array and **object** can be replaced with arrayOf and **shape**, respectively.

So, I did this in my project:

```
class X extends React.Component {
....
}

X.propTypes = {
    somePorp: PropTypes.shape.isRequired, // this cause an warnning in firefox, but satisfied eslint syntax check
    somePorp: PropTypes.object.isRequired, // no warnning in firefox, but can not satisfy eslint syntax check
}
```

**Question**:

How can I avoid warning message in firefox, as well as pass eslint syntax check (it's better no modification of eslint default rule)?

*BTW: firefox warning is something like below*

> *Warning: Failed prop type: X: prop type `classes` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **define the shape** of the prop. If you're unsure, simply `console.log()` the prop and view it's make up. [Click here to view the available PropType declarations](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage).

For example, if you were to utilize `redux` store as `this.props.store` or `history` from `react-router-dom` as `this.props.history`:

[image]

```
history: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,       // object of funcs
store: PropTypes.shape({                                      // shape of...
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,                          // func
  getState: PropTypes.func.isRequired,                          // func
  liftedStore: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.func).isRequired,   // object of funcs
  replaceReducer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,                    // func
  subscribe: PropTypes.func.isRequired,                         // func
  Symbol: PropTypes.func.isRequired,                            // func
}).isRequired
```

Be careful when using `isRequired`, because sometimes the function/array/object/value/etc may or may not exist. For the example above, all of them should be present upon component mount.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply;) there is 2 problems:  1. what if there is dynamic field(s) in shape definition? 2. what if there is nested object definition ? So, I guess the quickest resolution is enable object definition in .eslintrc rule file ....

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's dynamic if it follows a similar pattern (like an array of objects, or array of funcs, array of strings...etc). If it doesn't follow a repeated pattern, then you'll either need to create a custom function (as shown at the bottom of the `usage` docs) or disable prop-type validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following way:

```
X.propTypes = {
    somePorp:  PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object()),  
}
```